# Why the update method in the tiny Scrollbar jQuery plugin is not working in this script?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollbar, tinyscrollbar

I am using the tinyScrollbar Jquery plugin http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/ on a div which is on page load has display:none so i have to use the update method when it is made visible (as the documentation says) but the update method is not working.. here is the code:

```
$("#list-scrollbar").tinyscrollbar();
$(".playlist-drop-btn").click(function(){
                $(".audio .drop").slideToggle(200);
                $(".playlist-drop-btn").toggleClass("up");
                $("#list-scrollbar").update();
            });
```

note: when I make the div on page load display:block it works correctly.

Comment: Don't forget to update your tinyscrollbar js to a recent version. `tinyscrollbar_update()` was not available prior to 2011.

Comment: @Haluk and now tinyscrollbar_update is not available in the latest version.

Answer (score 3):

The function you need to call is tinyscrollbar_update()

```
$("#list-scrollbar").tinyscrollbar();
$(".playlist-drop-btn").click(function(){
            $(".audio .drop").slideToggle(200);
            $(".playlist-drop-btn").toggleClass("up");
            $("#list-scrollbar").tinyscrollbar_update();
        });
```

It is listed on the homepage at the very bottom: http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/

Answer (score -1):

You should do this:

```
var oScrollbar = $("#list-scrollbar");
oScrollbar.tinyscrollbar();
$(".playlist-drop-btn").click(function(){
                $(".audio .drop").slideToggle(200);
                $(".playlist-drop-btn").toggleClass("up");
                oScrollbar.update();
            });
```

Comment: use oScrollbar.tinyscrollbar_update(); instead of oScrollbar.update();

Comment: Additionally, declaring oScrollBar outside of the anonymous function won't work. The context changes and access to oScrollbar is lost.

Answer (score -1):

```
var $scrollbar= $('#list-scrollbar');
$scrollbar.tinyscrollbar();
var scrolbar1=$scrollbar.data("plugin_tinyscrollbar");
scrollbar1.update();
```

Comment: can you explain what your solution does? What was the problem and how your solution solves it? This is for further reference from other users that will look for the same or similar issue